# When Battle Royale mode will be added to Dota2?

Tags: dota-2

With all the latest news, it seems it will be added sooner or later. What is the estimate when that mode will be added to Dota2?

Would it be a custom game like pudge-wars, fully supported game mode, or some kind of expansion?

Answer (score 2):

[Here it is](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1412984203).

[The Underhollow](https://dota2.gamepedia.com/The_Underhollow), originally only available to players who purchased the 2018 International Battle Pass, is available as a custom game this very moment.

Comment: That mode don't have shrinking map area as a core of its gameplay.

Comment: @kusoksna Yes it does.